# Binance API get Spot asset balances

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested, binance-api-client

Im trying to get the balance of my Spot wallet assets from my Binance acount.

What I've tried:

```
bal = client.get_account()

print(bal)
```

Returned:

```
    "makerCommission": 15,
    "takerCommission": 15,
    "buyerCommission": 0,
    "sellerCommission": 0,
    "canTrade": true,
    "canWithdraw": true,
    "canDeposit": true,
    "balances": [
        {
            "asset": "BTC",
            "free": "4723846.89208129",
            "locked": "0.00000000"
        },
        {
            "asset": "LTC",
            "free": "4763368.68006011",
            "locked": "0.00000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

So to get to the balance values I tried:

```
bal = client.get_account()

for i in bal:
    if(i == 'balances'):
        for e in i:
            print(e)
```

But this returned this:

```
b
a
l
a
n
c
e
s
```

So how can I access my asset balances?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_asset_balance()` method directly

```
client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
```

or try to extract the values from the nested dictionary `bal` as follows:

```
if "balances" in bal: 
    for b in bal['balances']:
        print(b)
```